# Why can't constructors be final, static, or abstract?

Tags: java, syntax, constructor

Why can't constructors be final, static, or abstract in Java?

For instance, can you explain to me why this is not valid?

```
public class K {

    abstract public K() {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: consider what each of those keywords do for other methods. Sometimes it makes no sense in the context of a constructor, other times it is implied already.

Comment: Why would you want a static constructor? This question sounds like it's a homework problem.

Answer (score 177, accepted):

When you set a method as `final` it means: *"I don't want any class override it."*  But according to the Java Language Specification:

> [JLS 8.8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8) - "Constructor declarations are not members. They are never inherited and therefore are not subject to hiding or overriding."

When you set a method as `abstract` it means: *"This method doesn't have a body and it should be implemented in a child class."*  But the constructor is called implicitly when the `new` keyword is used so it can't lack a body.

When you set a method as `static` it means: *"This method belongs to the class, not a particular object."*  But the constructor is implicitly called to initialize an object, so there is no purpose in having a static constructor.

Comment: What is JLS? it might be useful to some if you explain this acronym when first used. It's ok I put this in for you.

Comment: JLS is acronym for Java Language Specification

Comment: I was asked this question in a technical phone screen today and didn't know  but it sounded as if I could not put final before a constructor declaration.

Comment: It could be useful to have an "abstract" constructor signature provided in an interface, meaning: "any class that implements this interface must provide a constructor with this signature". Currently, an interface can informally document that implementing classes should create constructors with specific signatures, but there is no design pattern in Java that will enforce or check this.

Answer (score 42):

The question really is why you want constructor to be `static or abstract or final`.

> Constructors aren't inherited so can't be overridden so whats the use
>   to have final constructor
>
> Constructor is called automatically when an instance of the class is
>   created, it has access to instance fields of the class. What will be
>   the use of a static constructor.
>
> Constructor can't be overridden so what will you do with an abstract
>   constructor.

Answer (score 18):

A Java constructor is *implicitly* final, the static / non-static aspects of its semantics are *implicit*<sup>1</sup>, and it is *meaningless* for a Java constructor to be abstract.

This means that the `final` and `static` modifiers would be redundant, and the `abstract` keyword would have no meaning at all.

Naturally, the Java designers didn't see in any point in allowing redundant and/or meaningless access modifiers on constructors ... so these are not allowed by the Java grammar.

Aside: It is a shame that they didn't make the same design call for interface methods where the `public` and `abstract` modifiers are also redundant, but allowed anyway.  Perhaps there is some (ancient) historical reason for this.  But either way, it cannot be fixed without rendering (probably) millions of existing Java programs uncompilable.

---

<sup>1 - Actually, constructors have a mixture of static and non-static semantics.  You can't "call" a constructor on an instance, and it they are not inherited, or overridable.  This is similar to the way static methods work.  On the other hand, the body of a constructor can refer to `this`, and call instance methods ... like an instance method.  And then there is constructor chaining, which is unique to constructors.  But the real point is that these semantics are fixed, and there is no point allowing a redundant and probably confusing `static` modifier.</sup>

Answer (score 9):

- **`public` constructor**: Objects can be created anywhere.
- **default constructor**: Objects can be created only in the same package.
- **`protected` constructor**: Objects can be created by classes outside the package only if it's a subclass.
- **`private` constructor**: Object can only be created inside the class (e.g., when implementing a singleton).

The `static`, `final` and `abstract` keywords are not meaningful for a constructor because:

- `static` members belong to a class, but the constructor is needed to create an object.
- An `abstract` class is a partially implemented class, which contains abstract methods to be implemented in child class.
- `final` restricts  modification: variables become constant, methods can't be overridden, and classes can't be inherited.

Answer (score 6):

**Final**: Because you can't overwrite/extend a constructor anyway. You can extend a class (to prevent that you make it final) or overwrite a method (to prevent that you make it final), but there is nothing like this for constructors.

**Static**: If you look at the execution a constructor is not static (it can access instance fields), if you look at the caller side it is (kind of) static (you call it without having an instance. Its hard to imagine a constructor being completely static or not static and without having a semantic separation between those two things it doesn't make sense to distinguish them with a modifier.

**Abstract**: Abstract makes only sense in the presence of overwriting/extension, so the same argument as for 'final' applies

Answer (score 6):

No Constructors can NEVER be declared as final. Your compiler will always give an error of the type "modifier final not allowed"
Final, when applied to methods, means that the method cannot be overridden in a subclass. 
Constructors are NOT ordinary methods. (different rules apply)
Additionally, Constructors are NEVER inherited. So there is NO SENSE in declaring it final.

Answer (score 3):

1. Constructors are NOT ordinary methods. (different rules apply)
2. Additionally, Constructors are NEVER inherited. So there is NO SENSE in declaring it final.
   **No Constructors can NEVER be declared final. YOur compiler will always give an error of the type "modifer final not allowed"**
3. Check the JLS Section 8.8.3 (The JLS & API docs should be some of your primary sources of information).

Answer (score 2):

JLS [section 8](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/classes.html) mentions this.

> Constructors (§8.8) are **similar to methods**, but cannot be invoked
>   directly by a method call; they are used to initialize new class
>   instances. Like methods, they may be overloaded (§8.8.8).

But constructors per say are not regular methods. They can't be compared as such.

Answer (score 1):

why constructor can not be static and final are well defined in above answers.

Abstract: "Abstract" means no implementation . and it can only be implemented via inheritance. So when we extends some class, all of parent class members are inherited in sub-class(child class) except "Constructor". So, lets suppose, you some how manage to declare constructor "Abstract", than how can you give its implementation in sub class, when constructor does not get inherit in child-class?

that's why constructor can't be 
abstract .

Answer (score 0):

lets see first
final public K(){

*above the modifier final is restrict 'cause if it final then some situation where in some other class or same class only we will override it so thats not gonna happen here proximately not final
eg:

```
we want public void(int i,String name){
//this code not allowed
```

let static,, static itz all about class level but we create the object based constructor by using 'new' keyword so,,,,,, thatsall

abstract itz worst about here not at 'cause not have any abstract method or any declared method

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately in PHP the compiler does not raise any issue for both `abstract` and `final` constructor.

```
<?php

abstract class AbstractClass 
{
   public abstract function __construct();
}

class NormalClass 
{
    public final function __construct() {
        echo "Final constructor in a normal class!";
    }
}
```

In PHP `static` constructor is not allowed and will raise `fatal` exception.

Here in `AbstractClass` obviously a constructor either can be declared as *abstract plus not implemented* or it can be declared as *something among (`final`, `public`, `private`, `protected`) plus a function body*.

Some other related facts on PHP:

1. In PHP having multiple constructor `__construct()` is not possible.
2. In PHP a constructor `__construct()` can be declared as `abstract`, `final`, `public`, `private` and `protected`!

**This code was tested and stood true for in PHP versions from 5.6 up to 7.4!**