# Why a constructor cannot be final?

Tags: java, constructor, final

As we all know constructor cannot be overridden. So when we declare a constructor as `final`, why does it give compile time error? As `final` keyword will also let a constructor not to override.

Comment: what language do you mean?

Comment: Constructors are not ordinary methods. Constructors are never inherited, so there is no sense in declaring them final.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9477476/why-constructors-cannot-be-final

Answer (score 0):

Only `public`,`private`,`protected` are allowed as modifiers. `final` is an not allowed as per the `JLS`. `final`  in java is to restrict the extension.

In java `constructors` can not be overridden. Super class's constructor is always called from any Constructor of the base class (implicitly or explicitly). `final` is used to prevent any method from being overridden, constructors are not like normal methods and also can not be `overridden`. making `constructors` as `final` will not make any sense. Making this will not be defined as any feature.

You can make the class as final if you wish to prevent its extension. If you wish to restrict the constructor of an class just make it private.

Answer (score 0):

No `Constructors` can NEVER be declared `final`. Your compiler will always give an error of the type "modifer `final` not allowed"
Final, when applied to methods, means that the method cannot be overridden in a subclass. 
Constructors are NOT ordinary methods. (different rules apply)
Additionally, Constructors are NEVER inherited. So there is NO SENSE in declaring it final.